# Android - AppWidgets, AlarmManager and AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-appwidget

I'm not having much luck with updating an app widget with `AlarmManager` generated broadcasts. Here's what I do:

Initializing `AlarmManager` on `AppWidgetProvider#onEnabled`

```
AlarmManager alarms = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarms.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, 
SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 60000, pendingIntent);
```

I also define `BroadcastReceiver` that simply listens for the updates that fired by the `AlarmManager`. When update is fired code runs `AsyncTask` that makes a network call. When the `AsyncTask` is completed (`onPostExecute`) it uses previously obtained instance of `AppWidgetManager` to update the widget(s).

It all actually runs well until in the logs I see message after which the `AlarmManager` never fires another update:

> Process com.foo.myapp (pid 12345) has died

Do I need to have some sort of check which will restart the alarms? For example when user access the parent app of the widget? How do I ensure that I can complete the long running task and come back to the widget if my app dies in the middle of the request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When update is fired code runs
>   AsyncTask that makes a network call.

If this is inside the `BroadcastReceiver`, that won't work. You cannot safely fork threads from a `BroadcastReceiver`, and `AsyncTask` effectively forks a thread to do its task asynchronously.

Instead, you should delegate long-running work to a [service started from the alarm](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/SystemServices/Alarm/) `BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: OK, I buy that - what I don't understand: why my alarm never re-fires after the app is killed? Or is it because the BroadcastReceiver dies with the app? But then, even if I run the service what happens if the app is killed the same way? I think I'm missing some fundamental knowledge here

Comment: Also - after starting the service and acquiring a lock should I then spawn a thread for my long-running task or just run it as part of the service?

Comment: I do not know why AlarmManager never fires again, but I recommend fixing the known problem (forking a thread in BroadcastReceiver) and hope that clears up the unknown problem (lobotomized alarm). IntentService automatically runs onHandleIntent() in a background thread, so you do not need to fork your own if you are using IntentService.

Comment: Thanks Mark - trying it this morning but oh, boy why this has to be so complicated?!

Comment: BTW - as a side note. Mark has great overview (my last nigh bedtime reading) of this in Advanced Android chapter 13